# how to show perl printf with decimal as a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
n=3    
awk "BEGIN {printf \"%.\"$n\"f\", (2*2.22222222)}"
```

result: 4.444

but:

```
perl -e "printf \"%.3f\", (2*2.22222222)"
```

how to replace 3 with n in perl cmd?

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to do this. You can probably find some waty of doing it with perl as you did with awk, but really you shouldn't do it that way for either. Here are a few cleaner ways for both perl and awk:

```
$ awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN{printf "%."n"f\n", (2*2.22222222)}'
4.444
```

Or, better, using awk's internal output format variable (`OFMT`), like this (thanks @steeldriver):

```
$ awk -v OFMT="%.${n}f" 'BEGIN{print (2*2.22222222)}'
4.444
```

And, in Perl, define a variable that holds the printf format, and then pass the number you want as an argument at runtime so it will be the first element of the ARGV array (`$ARGV[0]`):

```
$ perl -e '$frmt="%.$ARGV[0]f\n"; printf $frmt, (2*2.22222222);' $n
4.444
```

Alternatively, export the shell variable `n` so it can be read by perl as `$ENV{n}`:

```
$ export n
$ perl -e '$frmt="%.$ENV{n}f\n"; printf $frmt, (2*2.22222222);' 
4.444
```